# Tossing a coin 10 times

Tags: probability, statistics

> a) Given that exactly one head occurred, what is the probability that
>   it occurred on the first toss.

I have this so far, and I just need help computing the numerator:

Total outcome $= 2^{10} = 1024$

Probability of $1$ head $= \frac{10}{1024} = 0.0098$

$$P(\text{first toss} \lor \text{one head}) = \frac{P(\text{first toss }\land \text{ one head})}{P(\text{one head})},$$

but I don't know how to compute $P(\text{first toss } \land \text{ one head})$

> b) Given that the first two tosses were heads, what is the probability
>   that there were exactly $3$ heads?

I don't have much for this one and I don't know how to compute the numerator or the denominator

Probability of $3$ heads $= \frac{C^{10}_3}{1024} = \frac{120}{1024} = 0.1172$

$$P(\text{3 heads }\lor \text{ first two toss are heads})= \frac{P(\text{3 heads }\land \text{ first two toss are heads})}{P(\text{first two toss are heads})}$$

Comment: a) There are $10$ equally probable cases of exactly $1$ head out of $10$ tosses, hence the probability is $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: You must use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here

Comment: b) The probability of exactly $1$ head out of $8$ tosses is $\binom81\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^8=\frac{1}{32}$.

Comment: @barakmanos: i already got that part, and it's 10 toss not 8. I just need help with P(A|B). P(A|B) =P(A&B)/P(B) where A is the first toss and B is one head. I don't know how to compute P(A & B).

Comment: @StubbornAtom: Sorry but it's not 1/10. I have to use the formula  P(A|B) =P(A&B)/P(B) because it said "given" a certain event, I need to compute the first toss.

Comment: @Ayechan_San: It's $8$ tosses. $2$ have already taken place and are therefore not relevant.

Comment: And hmmm, StubbornAtom did not tell you anything about "$1/10$", so it is not really clear what you mean by that comment anyhow.

Comment: @barakmanos what do you mean? We know that we have 1 head 9 tails. It's asking that what is the probability of the 1 head occurring on the first toss given that particular event.

Comment: "Given that exactly one head occurred" - $1$ head out of $10$ tosses have occurred. There are $10$ equally probable such cases - HTTTTTTTTT, THTTTTTTTT, TTHTTTTTTT and so on... Hence the probability of this specific case is $1/10$.

Comment: So if you have probability of at least 7 heads given 2 tails, would you just do 7/10 * 8/10 ?

Comment: I was referring to the first question in that comment. And in short, both questions are easily solvable using simple logic. If you want to use the "official" formula for *conditional probability* then that's fine, but you will end up with the same results (neither one of which is mentioned in your answer).

Comment: BTW - "given $2$ tails" - where exactly is that even mentioned in the question???

Comment: I just needed help solving them using the formula. Because I have no idea how you got 1/10 and 1/32 because I've been taught with the P(A&B)/P(B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to use the conditional probability formula, you can.

There is one way to get exactly one head on the first toss of $10$: $HTTTTTTTTT.$  This is one out of $1024$ possible outcomes, so its probability is $1/1024.$

The probability of getting exactly one head (regardless of where) is $10/1024$.

Hence, the probability of getting a head on the first toss, given that you got only one head, is

$$P(A|B) = \frac{1/1024}{10/1024} = \frac{1}{10}.$$

For the second one: The probability of exactly three heads *and* two of the three falling on the first two tosses is $8/1024$ (just by counting them).  The probability of getting the first two tosses come up heads is $1/4$.  Hence the probability of getting exactly three heads, given the first two are heads, is

$$P(A|B) = \frac{8/1024}{1/4} = \frac{1}{32}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for a really helpful and clear answer. This is exactly what I needed. Could you please help with part B too? I don't know how to get the numerator or the denominator for this one.

Comment: Would it be (120/1024)/(2/1024)?

Comment: Edited my answer with the second part.